# Case issue in erlang

Tags: erlang, case

Working with Erlang's case, I'm facing a problem. The problem is the following:

```
other languages:
switch(A) 
{
  case "A" : case "B" :
   //do something
  break;
}
```

So, how to achieve the same thing using Erlang? Because sometimes it is very important to put conditions like these, to avoid overhead.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "overhead". Are you looking for efficiency in terms of required typing or required processing? If you mean processing, some languages (e.g. C) have an efficient way of processing case statements but others -- most languages, I'd wager -- treat them in practice as long if-else chains and do a comparison for each case.

Answer (score 6):

May be [guards](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Erlang_Programming/guards) are what you want.

```
the_answer_is(N) when A == "A"; A == "B";
```

; - is OR
   , - is AND

Comment: `;` is `orelse`, `,` is `andalso`: These operaters differ from `and` and `or` because they evaluate the right-side argument only if needed.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* use **case** expressions in Erlang. The syntax is:

```
case Expression of
    Pattern1 [when Guard1] -> Expr_seq1;
    Pattern2 [when Guard2] -> Expr_seq2;
    ...
end
```

To quote Pragmatic Erlang:

> **case** is evaluated as follows. First,
>   *Expression* is evaluated; assume this
>   evaluates to *Value*. Thereafter, *Value*
>   is matched in turn against *Pattern1*
>   (with the optional guard *Guard1*),
>   *Pattern2*, and so on, until a match is
>   found. As soon as a match is found,
>   then the corresponding expression
>   sequence is evaluated—the result of
>   evaluating the expression sequence is
>   the value of the case expression. If
>   none of the patterns match, then an
>   exception is raised.

An example:

```
filter(P, [H|T]) ->
    case P(H) of
        true -> [H|filter(P, T)];
        false -> filter(P, T)
    end;
filter(P, []) ->
    [].
```

filter(P , L); returns a list of all those elements X in L for which P(X) is true. This can be written using pattern matching, but the **case** construct makes the code cleaner. Note that choosing between pattern matching and case expressions is a matter of taste, style and experience.

Answer (score 4):

Not my favorite style, but you can do something like:

```
case A of
  _ when A == "A";
         A == "B" -> do_ab();
  _ when A == "C";
  _ when A == "D" -> do_cd();
  _               -> do_default()
end.
```

Comment: Ugh, writing conditions using case that ignore the actual pattern match is ugly.

Comment: I agree. If you have a neater answer to the question, go ahead. I usually run into this pitfall of answering the question. Not that it ever yields appreciation :)